# Is there a name for functions that are their own inverses

Tags: terminology

There are terms for various kinds of functions (or operators) such as...

```
associative - (a # b) # c  =  a # (b # c)
commutative - a # b  =  b # a
idempotent  - f (f (x)) = f (x)
```

Is there a similar name for functions that are their own inverse?

```
f (f (x)) = x
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called as an [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: Thanks - have to wait a few minutes before I can accept, but this is the answer.

Comment: Some examples of involutions are shown [here](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/education/wiener.pdf)

Comment: The most trivial involution is f(x) = x.

Answer (score 6):

Such a function is called an [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29).